# Join two tables without unique records and compare two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to Join two tables without unique fields and compare it based on the date.

Consider the following

#### Table A

```
System ID   Start   Process
132 1/17/2010   10/17/2010
132 2/21/2011   2/23/2011
132 1/16/2010   1/30/2010
132 1/16/2006   1/16/2006
132 1/16/2011   1/24/2010
132 1/30/2011   1/31/2011
132 1/30/2008   2/6/2008
132 2/5/2007    2/8/2007
132 2/5/2009    2/6/2009
```

#### Table B

```
System ID   T start T end
132 05/01/10    4/30/2011
132 05/01/11    4/30/2013
```

#### Output Table

```
System ID   Start       Process     Check
132 1/17/2010       10/17/2010      Y
132 2/21/2011       2/23/2011       Y
132 1/16/2010       1/30/2010       Y
132 1/16/2006       1/16/2006       N
132 1/16/2011       1/24/2010       Y
132 1/30/2011       1/31/2011       Y
132 1/30/2008       2/6/2008        N
132 2/5/2007        2/8/2007        N
132 2/5/2009        2/6/2009        N
```

I am trying to consider all the records in table A and compare the Table As column “Start” with the Tables Bs “T start” and “T End”, if the Table A’s “Start” appears between Table Bs “T Start” and “ T End” then the Column “Check” in the output table will be updated as “Y”.

I understood that the Tables can be joined only based on the unique fields ,so I tried to add an auto increment field in one of the table to avoid the duplication but the problem is both the tables consist of non-unique records and each record should be considered to identify the date. The total number of records in each table is around 60K. I am bit struck. I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: You may highlight code blocks and `ctl-k` or click the `{}` to mass-indent them 4 spaces for code/table formatting\

Comment: Joins don't necessarily have to occur on unique rows, but it isn't clear what you are actually trying to accomplish here.  What is Table A, what is Table B, and what is the relationship between them? In your output, what is `Check`? You need to be clearer about what it is you want to do here.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will make note of it. The only relationship between two tables are the "System ID", I am trying to compare Table A's “Start” with Table B's “T Start” and “T End” and update the column “Check” in the output table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to determine where dates in the two tables overlap.  The following should do this:

```
select a.*, (case when b.start is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as check
from TableA a left outer join
     TableB b
     on a.start <= b.Tend and
        a.end >= b.Tstart and
        (a.start <> b.Tstart and a.end <> b.Tend) and
        a.SystemId = b.SystemId;
```

Tables can be joined using any type of relation.  When you say on "unique fields" you might be referring to an "equijoin".  This is when the join conditions consist of "equals" between various fields.  The advantage to equijoins is that they are more efficient to process (under most circumstances).

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I really appreciate it. I will start exploring it.

Comment: Hi Gordan, I tried both the suggestions; I made a change by adding a Auto increment field to your logic to avoid duplication. The result is either Y for all or N for all. I am not sure what is happening.  I tried replicating the data set and tried the same, it works fine with my duplicate dataset but it doesn’t work with my actual dataset. I am not sure why it is not working? I verified the dataset, it seems to be fine. Any suggestions to validate my dataset?  System Id is varchar and rest of the fields are datetime.

Comment: @sasecse . . . I'm not sure if system id is also needed for the join.  In the question, there is only one system id, but if there are multiple values, then all records would probably match something.  Also, a record matches itself (due to `<=` and `>=`), which I just fixed.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for the update. I am not sure why this logic works with my data set. I trying with a manual sample again.

Answer (score 0):

When you checking for overlapping, you must be careful when joining tables, if, for example, you have 2 range of dates in table B which are overlapping with given range in table A, row from table A will appear in results twice. Hence, I suggest to use `exists` for checking overlapping:

```
select
    A.*,
    case
        when exists
        (
             select *
             from TableB as B
             where B.[System ID] = A.[System ID] and B.[T end] >= A.[Start] and B.[T start] <= A.[Process]
        )
        then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    end as [Checked]
from TableA as A
```

or use [apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
select
    A.*, case when B.[System ID] is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as [Checked]
from TableA as A
    outer apply (
        select top 1 *
        from TableB as B
        where B.[System ID] = A.[System ID] and B.[T end] >= A.[Start] and B.[T start] <= A.[Process]
    ) as B
```

see [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd145/2) example with your data.

Comment: Thanks for the Note. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Roman, I tried the above logic by adding one more Condition (using System ID) in my actual dataset But the result is either Y for all or N for all. I am not sure what is happening.  I tried replicating the data set and tried the same logic, it works fine with my duplicate dataset but it doesn’t work with my actual dataset. I am not sure why it is not working? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried using Exists and Join suggested by Gordon. Now I tried using Outer apply, I’m getting all as N.

Comment: could you paste a few rows from A and all rows from B so I could test it?

Comment: I think i don’t have enough permission to copy it. System Id is varchar and Start and End are datetime fields. I really apologize for that.

Comment: well it's really hard to say, you could see that query works on test case, if you gor all N, try to get one row from A for which you think there should be Y, test query on that row

Comment: Hi Roman, Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying with the manual sample.